# Map<String, String> in MappedSuperclass: Could not locate CollectionPersister for role when attempting a MapJoin. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate 5.2.7, and have created a new mapping:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "tagname", nullable = false)
@Column(name = "tagvalue", nullable = false)
private Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
```

When I include this in my Top-class, it works fine:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PersistentObject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private Long id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar creationDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar lastUpdate;

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "tagname", nullable = false)
@Column(name = "tagvalue", nullable = false)
private Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
```

The above works fine, all objects that inherit persistent object have a new table (ex: schedule_tags, role_tags, user_tags).

However, the following does NOT work:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class PersistentTaggedObject extends PersistentObject {

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "tagname", nullable = false)
@Column(name = "tagvalue", nullable = false)
private Map<String, String> tags = new HashMap<>();
```

In this scenario, I get an Exception:
**org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not locate CollectionPersister for role : de.ccsys.sns.models.PersistentObject.tags**

The exception happens at the last line (when calling **tagsMap.key()**):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> query = cb.createQuery(entityType);
Root<T> root = query.from(entityType);

MapJoin<T, String, String> tagsMap = root.joinMap("tags");
query.select(root).where(tagsMap.key().in(Arrays.asList(keys)));
```

What is strange to me to is that Hibernate appears to be searching this attribute in PersistentObject instead of PersistentTaggedObject.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the value of `entityType` in your last code block ? Does this type extends `PersistentTaggedObject` ? might it be `de.ccsys.sns.models.PersistentObject` ?

Comment: Yes, the type is a subclass of PersistentTaggedObject  which is a subclass of PersistentObject .

Comment: @user2037710 I am experiencing the same problem, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: See also this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12274

Comment: @GiovanniLovato Yes, I gave up on this and create an entity called Tag with the properties key and value ...  and add this as a Set in my object.